# PHP and SQL auto insert date and Time

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to auto insert date and time into my SQL database when a form is submitted from a php page

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tracker_msisdn_trace (msisdn, avis_name, date, colour, driver, 
driver_id, notes)
VALUES 
('$_POST[msisdn]','$_POST[avis_name]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[colour]','$_POST[driver]','$_POST
[driver_id]','$_POST[notes]')";
```

This is the code I use for Manual inserting data.

To auto insert the day I have tried the following

```
 $date = date("Y-m-d") 
 $_POST[".$date."]
```

I am not getting the date and time inserted into the SQL it shows 0000-00-00

This is my SQL table

## Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra

4   date    date            No  None

Assistance would be appreciated

Comment: In particular: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7545948/208809

Comment: It would be easier if you added a default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in your field. But you need to change the data type to datetime/timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
$date = date("Y-m-d") 
$_POST['date'] = $date
```

Otherway :

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tracker_msisdn_trace (msisdn, avis_name, date, colour, driver, 
driver_id, notes)
VALUES 
('$_POST[msisdn]','$_POST[avis_name]','". $date ."','$_POST[colour]','$_POST[driver]','$_POST
[driver_id]','$_POST[notes]')";
```